# Heroku running old deploy even after pushing a new deploy

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, scheduler

Old deploy had the code at line 34  -

```
for _ in range(HEX[0][0]):
```

but `HEX[0][0]` was a string, realizing this mistake I changed it to

```
for _ in range(len(HEX[0][0])):
```

and redeployed
but Heroku is still referring to the old code and giving the error

```
 2020-07-12T09:02:32.927382+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-07-12T09:02:32.927384+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/pytho
n3.6/site-packages/apscheduler/executors/base.py", line 125, in run_job
2020-07-12T09:02:32.927384+00:00 app[web.1]: retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.
kwargs)
2020-07-12T09:02:32.927385+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/finalDeploy.py", line 3
4, in timed_job_garbage
2020-07-12T09:02:32.927385+00:00 app[web.1]: for _ in range(HEX[0][0]):
2020-07-12T09:02:32.940876+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: 'str' object cannot be i
nterpreted as an integer
```

The code is in file `clock.py` which runs a custom clock for scheduling tasks but the error is showing on `finalDeploy.py`(which is my app file ) but the code doesn't even exist on finalDeploy.py.

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with heroku. I switched off the dynos from the dashboard and used `heroku ps:scale web=0` and `heroku ps:scale clock=0`. The app stopped 15 minutes after doing this! Then I simply changed the app name. Reinitialised the git and heroku repositories using `git init .` and  `heroku git:remote -a <new app name>` and then redeployed. The app worked fine after that.